# Do I have to process a Query to ensure that Implications are asserted as Facts?

Tags: nxbre

Tried to get this cleared from the Implementation doc; but I could only get that Implication and Queries are similar beasts. I also read [Simple Facts & Queries](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/nxbre/wiki/SimpleFactsAndQueries), but that did not help on this count.

I commented out the Query section in my rule file and processed. The Implications were not asserted...I check this by dumping all Facts to a flat file.

I was hoping that Implications get Asserted during Process, even without a query, so that I can persist all the Facts (basic Facts asserted from VB & Implicated Facts) in a DB and then use it for certain stuff.
Any way out ?

Thanks

Comment: Indeed Implications get Asserted during Process and no Query is needed for this to happen, so really I don't get the issue you're facing. Maybe show a bit of configuration and what failed with it?

Comment: Sigh! Turns out the issue is me:-( I kept going up and down in the persisted Factfile for the Implications with Head & Body, without realizing that they would be asserted as a Fact atom. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed Implications get Asserted during Process and no Query is needed for this to happen: there must be something else at play that makes the rules behave erratically.